# How to create a folder in TFS 2015 to store the Build Definitions?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have been working on TFS 2017 update 3 from past couple of years and now I have started working in new team where they are using TFS 2015.

In TFS 2017 Web, all the Build Definitions we had we used to keep\save them into their respective folders as their was option of Manage Folder present under Build Tab but here in TFS 2015 Web, I don't the see the option of Manage Folders and have to keep\save all the Build Definitions under one tab.

Is there any extension available in the marketplace or way by which I keep all the Build Definition in a more organized way in TFS 2015?

Comment: Upgrading to something more recent not option? TFS2015 is pretty old already.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Manage tfs2015 doesnot support Manage Folders feature. And I failed to find an extension that was available on the marketplace to achieve this.

You need to upgrade tfs2015 to a newer version in order to use the Manage Folders feature.

You can check out below document for more information:

[Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=tfs-2015)

Comment: Actually, even I would love to see the TFS upgraded to latest version but the team who manages the TFS says that the Development team has no requirement as off now or doesn't need any new feature. Hence, they won't upgrade.